# How to perform an update query in Java?

Tags: java, database, oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am not so into database and I have the following problem in a Java application that have to perform a very simple query that update a field on a table of my DB.

So, the original query is something like this:

```
UPDATE coda_tx c SET c.FK_STATO = 2 WHERE c.PK_CODA = 62816;
```

so I have implemented the following Java method that implement the previous query, this one:

```
public void updateStatus(int pkCoda, int newStatus) {

    String sql;

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    sb.append("UPDATE coda_tx c SET c.FK_STATO = ");
    sb.append(newStatus);
    sb.append(" WHERE c.PK_CODA = ");
    sb.append(pkCoda);

    sql = sb.toString();


    try {
        statment = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statment.executeQuery(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

My only doubt is related about the section by which the query is performed, this one:

```
statment = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statment.executeQuery(sql);
```

I think that this is wrong because actually there is **ResultSet** that is an object used to retrieve rows by a **SELECT** operation. In this case I am updating a field of a specific row and I am not retrieving rows putting theme into a **ResultSet** object.

So, how can I correctly handle this situation? How have I to perform my query?

Comment: you're looking for `statement.execute(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it:

```
// updateCount contains the number of updated rows
int updateCount = statment.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `statement.executeUpdate()` which will return the number of rows affected by the update.

> int executeUpdate(String sql) throws SQLException 
>   Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

If your method recives for example two variables like fkStato and pkCoda, that contains the value you want, you can make a simple query:

```
int fkStato=2;
int pkCoda=62816;
try
  {

    // create our java preparedstatement using a sql update query
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
      "UPDATE coda_tx c SET c.FK_STATO = ? WHERE c.PK_CODA = ?;");

    // set the preparedstatement parameters
    ps.setInt(1,fkStato);
    ps.setInt(2,pkCoda);

    // call executeUpdate to execute our sql update statement and returns number of rows affected
   int updateCount = ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.close();
  }
  catch (SQLException se)
  {
    // log the exception
    throw se;
  }
```